# How to use custom checkmark button image in a TableView while editing?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

[image]

I was trying to implement multiple selection for a tableview in swift as shown in the image. I did this by:

```
tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
```

Is it possible to change the checkmark image to a checkbox image?

Comment: Use `editingAccessoryView` of the `UITableViewCell`

Answer (score 0):

How about setting a custom accessory view when you begin editing your table view?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willBeginEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
        cell.editingAccessoryView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "custom_checkmark"))
    }
}
```